# Number of integers less than $N$ with $k$ prime divisors

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I recently asked an unsuccessful string of questions regarding $\#\{n<N, \omega(n)=k\}$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$. Is there some exact form of this that relies only on the usual number-theoretic functions ($\pi(x), \zeta(x), v(x), \phi(x), \mu(x)$, [and others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function))? I am not interested in asymptotically or approximately equal functions, or in bounds involving [big- or little-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). I'd like to use the equation alongside other number-theoretic functions.

I've been trying something along the lines of

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor \cos^{-1} \bigl( {\frac{k}{\omega(n)}-\lfloor \frac{k}{\omega(n)} \rfloor} \bigr)\rfloor,$$ but obviously that's not very helpful with all the floors.

Comment: Can you express $\sum_{n \le N, \omega(n) = 2} 1$ from $\pi(x)$ ? What do  you obtain for $k =3$ ?

Comment: Just a note: the usual name of your $w$ function is $\omega$.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#%CE%A9(n),_%CF%89(n),_%CE%BDp(n)_%E2%80%93_prime_power_decomposition

Comment: @MatthewConroy Thanks, I've edited.

Comment: allo... $\sum_{n \le x, \omega(n) =2} 1 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p^k \le x} \sum_{q^m \le x/p} 1 - \sum_{p^{k} \le x, k \ge 2} 1$ $ = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p^k \le x} \Pi(x/p) - (\Pi(x)-\pi(x))$ $= \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x \Pi(y) \Pi(x/y)\frac{dy}{y}-(\Pi(x)-\pi(x))$ where $\Pi(x)  =\sum_{p^k \le x} 1 = \sum_k \pi(x^{1/k})$. What do you get for $\sum_{n \le x, \omega(n) =3} 1$ ?

Comment: @reuns So I assume that $p,q$ are primes. For $w(n)=3$, I would need to extend your argument to a triple sum, and have a coefficient of $\frac{1}{3}$. I don't quite see how to change the integral.

Comment: For $\omega(n)=3$ it will be $\frac{1}{6}\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x \int_1^y \Pi(z)\Pi(y/z)\frac{dz}{z} \Pi(x/y)\frac{dy}{y}$ plus some small terms to remove the few doublons $p^k q^l r^m$ with $p,q,r$ non distinct. Important : note how it is similar to $\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (\log \zeta(s))^k$ where $\log \zeta(s)$ is not very different to $\sum_p p^{-s}$ thus $(\log \zeta(s))^k$ is not very different to $\sum_{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k} (p_1 \ldots p_k)^{-s}$. itself not very different to $\sum_{n=1,\omega(n)=k}^\infty n^{-s}$.

Comment: @reuns I see my mistake with the coefficient, thanks. I see the similarities now that you've pointed them out, but how should I deal with the small terms? I'm interested in an exact form, preferably with no bounds or approximations.